# Javascript snippet not working in Chrome, but works in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, google-chrome, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a really basic snippet of javascript code that works in Internet Explorer, but not Google Chrome. Here's the line it breaks on:

```
var formChildren = document.getElementById('myForm').children;
```

This is the first line in my script. The error I receive is:

```
cannot read property 'children' of null.
```

Does anyone know if I'm missing something? I can't imagine why Chrome would error out on such a basic line.

This is part of an MVC 4 project if that makes any difference.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Do a console.log of `document.getElementById('myForm')`.  Does it print null?

Comment: It appears to be working in Chrome, at least in a simplified version: http://jsfiddle.net/XRFAb/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem is solved. Yes I did some extra testing and realized that I was able to use getElementsByName successfully on both IE and Chrome so I took a look and realized I forgot to add the Id to the form. It was still unexpected that IE knew what it element was without the id set, but the problem is solved.

Thank you Kyle and hackNightly, your input helped a lot in narrowing down my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Chrome actually does return `null` in an instance where it is unable to find an element with that ID. You could hide this error by using `(document.getElementById('myForm') || {}).children`